# I can ping a database, should I be able to connect with the correct credentials?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am able to ping a database server from my machine but am having a hard time connecting. Should I be able to connect or could there be other network features that are getting in the way?

I am trying to connect with Oracle SQL developer to an Oracle 11g R2 database.

Comment: "ping" just verifies that the host is up.  It doesn't even tell you if the database server is running, never mind if it's configured to accept credentials from you.

Comment: It would signify that there is an open network path to that server so I might be able to cross networking issue off my list?

Comment: Add to Paul's comment: And in the age of Netword Address Translation a ping might be answered by a router but if you connect with TCP the connection might be answered by the database server.

Comment: Pinging and connecting are two very different things. One means the host can be reached on the network (or at least its corresponding router), Connecting means that the database instance and its corresponding listener has been started and is able to process connect requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the instructions to connect to database using sql developer

- Know the port number on which database is listening (by default 1521)
- Make sure you can telnet to the host and the port number
- There are several ways, you can connect (BASIC, TNS, Advanced etc)
- For Basic, you need to give host ip or resolvable name, port and sid or service name as part of the connect string. Similarly for JDBC you need to give valid JDBC url and also you are supposed to ojdbc jar file in the appropriate location of sql developer.